# Как получить значение href в class="entry-title"

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Как получить все ссылки знаю. А как получить ссылку в конкретном случае? Как получить все ссылки в class="entry-title". Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://memepedia.ru/trending/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
array = soup.find_all(class_ = 'entry-title')
print(array)
```

Вывод программы:

```
[<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="https://memepedia.ru/bari-alibasov-i-krot/" rel="bookmark">Бари Алибасов и «Крот»</a></h2>]
```

Как получить "https://memepedia.ru/bari-alibasov-i-krot/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если извлекать из `array`, то можно, например, применить селектор на каждый элемент:

```
hrefs = [el.select('a')[0]['href'] for el in array]
```

Хотя как по мне, проще изначально использовать селектор:

```
hrefs = [el['href'] for el in soup.select('h2.entry-title a[href]')]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Рад был помочь!